# Shrink matrix to certain size

Tags: matlab, matrix, resize, average, reshape

I'm very new to MatLab. I'm working with huge matrices made by a sensor, so I'll be using smaller ones as examples for my question.

Suppose I have these 2 matrices

matrix 1

```
  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 6 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 4 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0
  0 2 2 6 0 1 3 1 2 1 1 3
  0 0 2 6 0 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
  0 2 4 0 1 0 0 2 2 1 2 0
```

matrix 2

```
  0 2 1 4 0 0 0 1 1 3 2 0
  0 2 1 2 5 0 1 2 3 3 1 0
  0 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 2 2 0 0
  2 2 2 2 0 1 0 3 2 2 2 0
  2 2 2 4 0 2 3 1 2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 4 0 2 0 3 2 2 3 2
  3 2 1 5 0 1 0 1 3 3 4 1
  0 3 1 6 0 1 1 2 3 2 2 1
  0 2 1 4 0 1 1 2 3 2 0 0
```

I would like to resize them into 2 matrices with the same size (say, 4 lines each) without losing the average values, so if we had an 8 line matrix, it would have to remove every other line and not the first or last 4 lines.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you can re-size without omitting data using `imresize` http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove every other row, you may use:

```
M(1:2:end,:)=[]
```

This does not maintain the average in all cases, the already mentioned `imresize` might be an option.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `imresize` (which is part of the Image Processing Toolbox). You can average every `n` rows by just playing a bit with dimensions and using [`mean`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html):

```
result = squeeze(mean(reshape(permute(matrix,[1 3 2]),n,[],size(matrix,2))))
```

For example:

```
matrix = [ 1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
           0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
           1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
           0     2     2     6     0     1     3     1
           0     0     2     6     0     1     2     1
           0     2     4     0     1     0     0     2 ];
n = 2;
```

give

```
result =

    0.5000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.5000         0         0
    0.5000    1.5000    1.5000    3.5000    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    0.5000
         0    1.0000    3.0000    3.0000    0.5000    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000
```